# SPFx Adaptive card API call Init()

Tags: spfx

I am new to Adaptive Cards (and TS), but I was able to complete most of the work except for one thing:

I would like to consume and parse API call on load (I think TS function is called init()). To be more specific: the adaptive card should display number of points for some rewards: I have API URL, JSON body that should pass username in SP, and then there is API key. Can someone point me either to a tutorial or just simply layout the way this async method should be written in TS.

Thank you.